# Website optimization tool

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, optimization

I'm reading some articles about website optimizisation and different ways to proceed. I've found lots of information about caching, minifying the css, regrouping css files...

Here is an exemple:

I'm building my website using Bootstrap but I'm not using all the css properties defined in the bootstrap files. It would probably be more efficient to remove those unused properties to have a more lightweight css file.

So, here's my question, Is there a software which can do that and the minifying and other "code side" optimization ?
If not why is it not possible ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

No, there isn't a tool that does it all in a simple step.

Yes you can configure some tools to do it. :)

You need a build process of some kind ( [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) for example )

Depends on which you choose there are tools or modules that can be configured.

You need to understand that there are a million possible optimization: for example if you compile bootstrap from less or sass you can simply [not include the sub-modules you don't use](https://jhipster.github.io/customizing_bootstrap.html), or you can minify and compress the final css / js. Or you can use something like [Critical Path CSS](https://jonassebastianohlsson.com/criticalpathcssgenerator/)

Comment: Thank you @kajyr ! Grunt looks really good.

Answer (score 0):

Customize your Bootstrap 
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Than read [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)

and search how to css,js [concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) and [minimize](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin)